# How to perform multiple functions on a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I am very new to python, and having gone through some exercises I thought it would be a good idea to write my first program! (Perhaps an overly ambitious goal).

I have a textfile and want to extract several pieces of information from it. The text file is an output file from stimulus delivery software, and is arranged in columns and lines.

I want the program to record how many times a certain string is present,and then also record two other pieces of information from the surrounding text in the file.

For example, from the following text:

```
RXXXX   9   Picture CATCH_QUAIL_600_5_3000_2590_278 1026069 7999    2   3000    3   7900    2960    other   0

RXXX    9   Picture poststim_fixation   1029236 0   1   25997   2   0   25900   other   0

RXXXX   9   Response    115 1036879 7643    1
```

I want it to report that there was a response, on trial number 9 and that the response was for the Picture 'CATCH_QUAIL'.

I think the best way to do this is for the program to find the string 'Response' and then extract the information from two lines above and from one column to the left.

So, this is what I have so far (I am sorry its pathetic):

```
    x= open('file')
    y= x.read()
    y.split()
    l= y.splitlines()
```

Then I know I need to make some loops which will cycle through the file, and if it finds the 'response' string then move to a new loop which will record the information I want- unfortunately I have no idea how to do this.

If at all possible, I really want to learn how to do this so if you could give me some hints rather than a complete code it would be great.

Having looked through some of the other questions on here, I am sorry if this is far below the caliber of question that you would expect but I am not sure where else to turn!

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: How do you tie a response to a picture? From your example, it seems the response is for "poststim_fixation" rather than "CATCH_QUAIL.."

Comment: 1. `y.split()` -- why are you discarding the return value? That line currently does nothing (except use CPU time). Well, splitlines() is what you really want to do anyway, so kill that line. 2. You only need one loop (look up `enumerate()` help and see if you can figure out why). 3. You can use 'in' (as in `'Response' in thisline`) to test whether a string contains another string.

Comment: @kampu thank you very much, I will have a play with that now.

Comment: @dhara yes, sorry that is probably confusing.Response will always be two lines below, it isn't straight after picture because of the delay between seeing the picture and responding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all for the help. I think it is clear that there are many ways one could go about doing this, below is the code that I arrived at- it is probably not the neatest, but I find it fairly transparent and easy to manipulate.

```
x= open('file')
logs=x.readlines()
iLine = logs[6]

log_enumerater = enumerate(logs)
for iLine in log_enumerater:
    if iLine[1].find('CATCH') != -1: 
            Event=iLine[1].split('\t')[3]
            word=Event.split('_')[1]
            t0=int(iLine[1].split('\t')[4])
            print iLine[1].split('\t')[3].split('_')[1], iLine[0]
            print 'Catch in line ', iLine[0] 
            myLine = int(iLine[0])+2
            print 'Response in Line', myLine
    if iLine[1].find('Response') != -1:
            t1= int(iLine[1].split('\t')[4])
            ResponseTime= t1-t0  
            print ResponseTime
```

I have been using it to get the trial numbers and now have adapted it slightly for getting response times.

Thank you again for all your help,

Ben

Comment: You could make your code a little more readable by changing the `for` loop to `for i, line in log_enumerater:` and then changing your references to `iLine[0]` to just `i` and `iLine[1]` to `line`. Also instead of `if iLine[1].find('CATCH') != -1:` you could use `if 'CATCH' in iLine[1]:` (or `if 'CATCH' in line:` if you've followed my first suggestion). Same for the `if iLine[1].find('Response') != -1:` line.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the python docs are a good place to start, check out the section on [reading/writing files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).  Mentioned there is a very useful pattern for working with files in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open("file", "r") as my_file:
  for i, my_line in enumerate(my_file):
    print i, my_line
```

This will open the file (`my_file`) for reading (option `"r"`), and then just print each line (`my_line`) and its position (`i`) for you.

The second useful pattern here is the **`enumerate()`** in the second line of the script  This takes a list, and for each item gives you back the item, and it's "index" or position in the list.  So, for example:

```
for index, item in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]):
  print index, ":", item
```

gives:

```
0 : a
1 : b
2 : c
```

Ok, now you might want to consider using the `in` keyword to search for the substring "Response" within the line:

```
if "Response" in my_line:
  print "found Response in line %s!" % i
```

try running the whole thing, and see what you get

```
with open("py-test.txt", "r") as my_file:
  for i,my_line in enumerate(my_file):
    print i, my_line
    if "Response" in my_line:
      print "found Response in line %s!" % i
```

so, now you're finding the line you want and getting its position in the file, you'll just need a way to access a specific line in the file, and access the information you need from that line..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response msturdy, stupidly I have only returned to look at any comments now and have actually done it a different way! But you are correct, the reading and writing files section is very helpful so thank you for pointing that out for me.

Comment: Glad to help!  the `with` pattern is something I wish I'd known about a while ago  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would read the information from the file and put it in a list-of-lists like this:

```
data = []
with open('textfile.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile.read().splitlines():
        if line:
            data.append(line.split())
print data
```

Result:

```
[['RXXXX', '9', 'Picture', 'CATCH_QUAIL_600_5_3000_2590_278', '1026069', '7999', '2', '3000', '3', '7900', '2960', 'other', '0'],
 ['RXXX', '9', 'Picture', 'poststim_fixation', '1029236', '0', '1', '25997', '2', '0', '25900', 'other', '0'],
 ['RXXXX', '9', 'Response', '115', '1036879', '7643', '1']]
```

That way you can access the contents of any column of any non-blank line, and it would allow you to look backwards at previous lines when necessary as shown below:

```
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if line[2] == 'Response':
        print 'Got response on trial numder', line[1]
        if data[i-2][2] == 'Picture' and data[i-2][3].startswith('CATCH_QUAIL'):
            print '  The response was for the picture', data[i-2][3]
```

Output:

```
Got response on trial numder 9
  The response was for the picture CATCH_QUAIL_600_5_3000_2590_278
```